# How to raise an exception from C++ that will trigger scripting exception handlers

Tags: c++, exception, com, atl, abi

I've been finding bits and pieces to this answer on the web, but not a crystal clear solution.

Here's what i'm trying to do.
1) Create an ATL Simple Object.
2) Add a method to that object which returns a BOOL, not an HRESULT.  The caller wants true/false return values.
3) Throw an exception to a jscript or vbscript caller that will provide e.description and e.number data.

RE 2) I've found that I can use STDMETHODIMP_(BOOL) along with [local] to allow BOOL to be returned RE 3) I've found that I can pass IErrorInfo via SetErrorInfo() to populate the Error object

My dilemma is I can't figure out how to architect C++ to throw an exception across the ABI boundary that won't crash the caller.

Comment: I don't believe you can throw C++ exceptions across ABI boundaries. How could that work?

Comment: Thanks for the input Mark.  So is there no way to trigger the catch block in a script from C++?  If not, what would you suggest I should do for the best implementation?  I believe I came across a post from someone that says you can do this via Invoke/InvokeEx but i'm not sure how to implement the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write code for a scripting client then you must use a subset of COM called Automation.  Which dictates that:

- all interfaces must be derived from IDispatch
- a coclass should implement only one source interface
- all methods must return a HRESULT, only STDMETHODIMP is valid
- argument types must be restricted to the subset permitted by Automation.

In particular that means that BOOL is not permitted, it must be VARIANT_BOOL.  You declare a method that returns a boolean by writing it like this in IDL:

```
 [id(42)] HRESULT Foo([out,retval] VARIANT_BOOL* retval);
```

Assign VARIANT_TRUE or VARIANT_FALSE to *retval in your code.  The scripting language uses natural syntax like `var = Foo()`.

You generate an exception in the scripting client by returning a failure HRESULT.

Comment: Hans thank you very much!  I'm a beginner to COM.  This worked perfect.

Comment: I have to say, that's certainly a happier response than I expected. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the client handle an 'exception' by

1. setting the IErrorInfo like you said
2. returning a non HRESULT hr != S_OK

So, you need IDispatch/Interop compatible interfaces, which require HRESULT return types (AFAIR).

<sup>IDL allows a lot more, but 'dynamic' clients like script hosts (VBS, JScript, VBA and others) don't consume those *natively*, so the interoperability will not be optimal.</sup>

Comment: Will this work if i'm returning STDMETHODIMP_(BOOL) as a return type, not HRESULT?  Also, will this invoke the scripting callers catch block automatically?  Or just return a number that I have to actively check on the caller end?

Comment: Nope, since that doesn't return a HRESULT. So yes, your left with oldfashioned manual (`C-style`) error checking

Comment: This is exactly as it is supposed to work. the nature of the error should be described in the error info instance, but the actual COM method should return with the fail-bit lit (0x80000000), which is exactly what sehe is describing.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig.  So do I have to sacrifice the ability to return a BOOL to the caller to get this to work then?  Or can I still send TRUE FALSE back?  The caller is expecting a bool.

Comment: + implement `ISupportErrorInfo` to indicate that `IErrorInfo` is effectively set and needs to be queried for.

Comment: Thanks Roman.  I had this part figured out.  I created the Simple Object with support for ISupportErrorInfo and i'm using ATLReportError() to populate IErrorInfo.